# Meaning of (+) in SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I've come across some SQL queries in Oracle that contain '(+)' and I have no idea what that means. Can someone explain its purpose or provide some examples of its use?
Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430274/oracle-what-does-do-in-a-where-clause). You may find some more information there.

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430274/oracle-what-does-do-in-a-where-clause

Comment: I actually tried searching for an answer before posting the question but didn't get any results when searching for '+' or '(+).
It's weird that the question title in the URL seems to skip the (+) part as well.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's Oracle's synonym for `OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM a, b
WHERE b.id(+) = a.id
```

gives same result as

```
SELECT *
FROM a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN b
     ON b.id = a.id
```

Comment: I'll note for the next person, pay attention to what's happened to the `a`'s and `b`'s here. In the example the from clause is `[a, b]`, but the equivalency check is `[b.id = a.id]`. My habit is to keep the equivalency `[a.id = b.id]`; so I misread the example. An hour of my life I won't get back ;^)

Comment: To that, I would interpret `(+)` as oracle's way of saying "this side gets nulls when no match can be found". Using my norm for equivalencies of `[a.id = b.id]`; then there's a mirror happening. If I'm re-writing the query to follow the modern standard, `[a.id = b.id(+)]` becomes a LEFT OUTER and `[a.id(+) = b.id]` becomes a RIGHT OUTER.

Comment: The thing is the (+) operator is placed directly in the conditional statement and on the side of the optional table (the one which is allowed to contain empty or null values within the conditional).

Answer (score 4):

The + is a short cut for OUTER JOIN, depending on which side you put it on, it indicates a LEFT or RIGHT OUTER JOIN

Check the second entry in [this forum post](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/79187/2/) for some examples

Answer (score 4):

You use this to assure that the table you're joining doesn't reduce the amount of records returned. So it's handy when you're joining to a table that may not have a record for every key you're joining on.

For example, if you were joining a Customer and Purchase table:

To list *all* customers and all their purchases, do an outer join (+) on the Purchase table so customers that haven't purchased anything still show up in your report.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, the + is used in older versions of Oracle to indicate an outer join in the pre-ANSI SQL join syntax. In other words:

```
select foo,bar
from a, b
where a.id = b.id+
```

is the equivalent of

```
select foo,bar
from a left outer join b
on a.id = b.id
```

NOTE: this may be backwards/slightly incorrect, as I've never used the pre-ANSI SQL syntax.

Comment: It's used in newer versions of Oracle for those of us who hate ANSI sql.

Comment: @Mark Brady exactly. I feel it makes the intent of the query more clear. And I also *hate* ANSI SQL.