# What is the meaning of the query?

Tags: sql, database

GUYS I KNOW (+) MEANS OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM email a,email_types b
WHERE a.user_id  (+)     =10
  AND a.email_id(+)=b.email_enum;

SELECT *
FROM email a,email_types b
WHERE a.user_id      =10
  AND a.email_id(+)=b.email_enum;
```

What is the meaning of `a.user_id  (+) = 10`? Is this equal to `a.user_id =10`, or do they have a different meaning?

What is the difference between the two queries?

`a.user_id (+) =10` is matched with which column `b`. The value 10 is matched with column of `b` table?

Comment: Old, deprecated Oracle outer join.

Comment: It's Oracle's synonym for OUTER JOIN.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517557/meaning-of-in-sql-queries

Comment: Implicit outer Join in oracle http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-joins.htm U may understand here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best explained by converting the Oracle syntax to standard SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM email a,email_types b
WHERE a.user_id  (+)     =10
  AND a.email_id(+)=b.email_enum;
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM email_types b
  LEFT JOIN email a ON a.email_id = b.email_enum AND a.user_id = 10;
```

Which means "do an outer join between email_types and email but only consider rows from the `email` table where `user_id` equals 10". It will return all rows from `email_types` and all matching emails (if there are any) from `user_id = 10` if there are no emails for that user, then no rows from the `email` table are considered.

If you remove the `(+)` operator from the original query's condition on the `user_id` column, it would be equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM email_types b
  LEFT JOIN email a
         ON a.email_id = b.email_enum 
WHERE a.user_id = 10;
```

which would result in an inner join because of the condition on the outer joined table.

Answer (score 2):

The `(+)` syntax is Oracle's old, outdated, syntax for an implicit outer join. The side with the `(+)` is the side that may not have matches, so this query will return all records with `b` with their counterparts in `a` where `a.user_id = 10`, or with `null`s if there's no matching `a` record.

Comment: a.user_id  (+)     =10 is matched with which column b. The value 10 is matched with column of b table.

Comment: And do the two queries behave differently?

Answer (score 0):

The (+) in the first join condition is required to ensure that the join is treated as an outer join as detailed in the Oracle [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm):

> If A and B are joined by multiple join conditions, then you must use the (+) operator in all of these conditions. If you do not, then Oracle Database will return only the rows resulting from a simple join, but without a warning or error to advise you that you do not have the results of an outer join.

The key thing to note here is that without that (+) in every join condition, you will end up with the results of an inner join, not an outer join.