# What does (+) do in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer to query an Oracle DB (not sure which version it is) and I'm going to use the SQL I make for a Crystal report.  Many of the reports the previous developers have written don't use JOIN keywords to make the joins (and I'm not too familiar with JOIN keywords as a result).

Many of the joins they make are made in the WHERE statement.  I'll notice something like this.

```
Select * From TableA, TableB WHERE TableA.PrimaryKey(+) = TableB.ForeignKey
```

My question is concerning the (+).  What purpose does it serve and how do I use it in my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not recommended. See this previous answer

[Difference between Oracle's plus (+) notation and ansi JOIN notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193654/different-between-oracles-plus-notation-over-ansi-join-notation)

Answer (score 8):

That represents a “right outer join” (right because the `=` is on the right side of the `+`).

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA, TableB
WHERE TableA.PrimaryKey(+) = TableB.ForeignKey
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TableB
  ON (TableA.PrimaryKey = TableB.ForeignKey)
```

Answer (score 3):

right outer join

Answer (score 0):

(+) is used to perform right outer join in Oracle 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN is one of the JOIN operations that allow you to specify a JOIN clause
For details 
http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj57522.html

Comment: The link you posted ist **not** for the Oracle database it's for **JavaDB** (aka "Derby")

Comment: I added that comment to get clear idea of what right outer join is