# (+) symbol in SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, join

Just i have came across a SQL query in one of the stored procedure like below:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    account a, 
    performance p,
    customer c, 
    override o
WHERE 
    a.account_id = p.account_id (+)
    AND a.account_id = c.account_id (+)
    AND o.override_type(+) = 'O'
```

Can you please explain what is the `(+)` symbol's play here? and the difference of using Left side and right side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does (+) do in Oracle SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376442/what-does-do-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: Though this is a better explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193654/difference-between-oracles-plus-notation-and-ansi-join-notation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the old syntax for `OUTER JOIN` in Oracle (I don't know whether there are other RDBMS that uses the same old syntax or not).

**Better off:** Use the explicit ANSI-92 `OUTER JOIN` syntax using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` instead of the `+` symbol.

Comment: This Stored procedure is somewhat 7 or 8 years old. Thanks for clearing my doubt.

Comment: @Sundar - You're welcome any time:) What RDBMS is this? Is it Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

`(+)` is an legacy outer join syntax in oracle (8 and before). **It is very restrictive and handles many cases just wrong.** Don't use it anymore. Oracle supports ansi joins (eg. `left outer join`) since version 9.

Comment: You're going to have to come up with proof for "handles many cases just wrong". It has various restrictions but not that much more than the ANSI syntax and sometimes still _has_ to be used because Oracle's implementation of the ANSI syntax sometimes results in incorrect query plans where the + syntax doesn't (though I prefer not to use it).

Comment: You can't for instance outer join from a table that is already outer joined (e.g. order outer join customer outer join address). You probably can't even join anymore after outer joining. There are issues when you have additional condition on an outer joined table. It's not really documented. The problem is that it doesn't complain when you write an invalid query. It just returns plain wrong data. Years ago I remember that I got values returned by the queries which appear nowhere on that column in the whole database. As much as I like Oracle databases, this outer joins are failed.