# What is the use of (+) operator in pl/sql?

Tags: operator-keyword

what is the meaning of (+) operator in pl/sql  eg:- rec.ptp_id= PTP.ptp_id(+)
Is it left outer join when we specify (+) in right?

Its outer join ,left outer join

Comment: I think you answered your own question. Its outer join. If on the left side, left outer join, and if on the right side, right outer join. I think it is not a recommended use anymore though. Still exists for legacy code.

Comment: Note that this question has already been answer here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376442/what-does-do-in-oracle-sql