# Is there alternative to inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join

Is there something different between this two codes

```
select a.firstname,
       a.lastname,
       b.salary,
       b.designation
from table a,
     table b
where a.id = b.id
```

and

```
select a.firstname,
       a.lastname,
       b.salary,
       b.designation
from table a inner join table b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functionally, no, these specific queries are the same. The second is using ANSI join syntax, which has been the standard since SQL-92, and available in Oracle [since 9i](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=213). Although both still work, there are some things you need to use ANSI syntax for when working with outer joins.

The new style is generally preferred, partly because the old style makes it possible to accidentally introduce cartesian products by omitting a join condition - which you can't do with `join` syntax (*accidentally*; you can still do a `cross join` if you really want to do that on purpose) and it arguably makes your join/filter intentions clearer. Many find it easier to read, but that's a matter of opinion so that aspect is off-topic.

[Oracle recommend you use ANSI joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries006.htm#i2054012), at least for outer joins. You can see from plans and traces that Oracle actually still translates ANSI syntax into its old format internally, so as long as your query is correct (i.e. no missing conditions) then there is no performance difference; and the optimiser can still choose to use indexes based on the `where` clause, not just the `on` clauses.

Many people here would recommend that you use ANSI syntax from the start if you're new to Oracle. Of course, not everyone agrees; there's a reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7810844/266304) to a dissenting voice, for example.