# Get data from database using php,ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a simple section in which I am displaying data from the database, my database looks like this.

Now I have four buttons  looks like this

When a user clicks one of the above buttons it displays this

So now  when user eg select `construction` and next select eg `Egypt' in the console and clicks button`confirm`displays [855,599075], user can select multiple countries, this works as expected for`construction `,`power`,`oil`,

Now I want if user eg clicks `All available industries` button in those four buttons and next select eg `Egypt` and click `confirm` it should display 
the sum of egypt total projects in construction, oil, power sector  `855+337+406` =`1598` and the sum of total budgets in both sectors `1136173`

Here is my solution

HTML

```
<div id="interactive-layers">
    <div buttonid="43" class="video-btns">
        <span class="label">Construction</span></div>
    <div buttonid="44" class="video-btns">
        <span class="label">Power</span></div>
    <div buttonid="45" class="video-btns">
        <span class="label">Oil</span></div>
    <div buttonid="103" class="video-btns">
        <span class="label">All available industries</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is js ajax

```
$("#interactive-layers").on("click", ".video-btns", function(){
    if( $(e.target).find("span.label").html()=="Confirm" ) {

        var selectedCountries = [];

        $('.video-btns .selected').each(function () {
            selectedCountries.push( $(this).parent().find("span.label").html() ) ;
        });

        if( selectedCountries.length>0 ) {
            if(selectedCountries.indexOf("All available countries")>-1) {
                selectedCountries = [];
            }


        } else {

            return;
        }

        var ajaxurl = "";
        if(selectedCountries.length>0) {
            ajaxurl = "data.php";
        } else {
            ajaxurl = "dataall.php";

        }

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                    countries: selectedCountries.join(","),
                    sector: selectedSector
            },
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                $(".video-btns").each(function () {
                    var getBtn = $(this).attr('buttonid');
                    if (getBtn == 106) {
                        var totalProjects = $("<span class='totalprojects'>"+ result[0] + "</span>");
                        $(this).append(totalProjects)
                    }else if(getBtn ==107){
                        var resultBudget = result[1]
                        var totalBudgets = $("<span class='totalbudget'>"+ '&#36m' +" " + resultBudget +"</span>");
                        $(this).append( totalBudgets)
                    }
                });
                return;
              }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is php to get all dataall.php

```
$selectedSectorByUser = $_POST['sector'];
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "love");
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM meed");
 $data = array();

 $wynik = [];
$totalProjects = 0;
$totalBudget = 0;

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    if($row['Sector']==$selectedSectorByUser ) {
     $totalProjects+= $row['SumofNoOfProjects'];
     $totalBudget+= $row['SumofTotalBudgetValue'];
    }
 }
 echo json_encode([ $totalProjects, $totalBudget ] );
exit();
?>
```

Here is data.php

```
<?php

$selectedSectorByUser = $_POST['sector'];
$countries = explode(",", $_POST['countries']);

//var_dump($countries);
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "meedadb");
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM meed");
 $data = array();

 $wynik = [];
$totalProjects = 0;
$totalBudget = 0;

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    if($row['Sector']==$selectedSectorByUser && in_array($row['Countries'],$countries ) ) {
    // array_push($data, $row);
     $totalProjects+= $row['SumofNoOfProjects'];
     $totalBudget+= $row['SumofTotalBudgetValue'];
    }
 }

 // array_push($wynik, $row);
 echo json_encode([ $totalProjects, $totalBudget ] );
//echo json_encode($data);
exit();
?>
```

Now when the user clicks `All available industries` btn and selects a country I  get  `[0,0]` on the console.

What do I need to change to get what I want? any help or suggestion will be appreciated,

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a database front-end, not a database. You don't get data from it.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: If you want to get data from multiple tables, either do multiple queries or use a JOIN. As a note, when dealing with countries it's often best to use numerical identifiers or standardized codes to avoid ambiguity or spelling errors. [ISO-3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) specifies codes for every country.

Comment: update your question and add  the expected result  ..  (use text ..not image)

Comment: updated the question check out with bount 100

Comment: @scaisEdge check now

Comment: @user9964622  i have added an asnwer with a suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in you dataAll.php

If you have select `All available industries`
you shold not check for sector  because you need all sector (eventually you should check for countries )
so you should avoid the check for this condition

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "love");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM meed");
$data = [];

$wynik = [];
$totalProjects = 0;
$totalBudget = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $totalProjects += $row['SumofNoOfProjects'];
    $totalBudget += $row['SumofTotalBudgetValue'];
}
echo json_encode([$totalProjects, $totalBudget]);
```

Comment: Hi scaris stil when I click a button All available industries and click algeria and clicking confirm I get [0,0] :(  am about  to give up now  but when I select a another sector eg construction or power or oil I get the result I want :( except for the all available industries btn :(

Comment: And what about ajax?  maybe I need to add if the condition for   `All available industries`?  because the dataall.php I am using to get data if a user  at the end clicks a button `All available countries` then the `dataall.php` is called and it returns me exactly what I want,

Answer (score 4):

You can use the SQL JOIN operator, or in this case an implicit join would be cleanest:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM construction, power, oil_and_gas, industrial WHERE construction.Countries = power.Countries AND power.Countries = oil_and_gas.Countries AND oil_and_gas.Countries = industrial.Countries");
```

You need the WHERE conditions so it knows how the rows of each different table are related to each other. You can shorten it a bit with aliases for the tables:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM construction as C, power as P, oil_and_gas as G, industrial as I WHERE C.Countries = P.Countries AND P.Countries = G.Countries AND G.Countries = I.Countries");
```

In this case, however, I think you may want to consider changing the structure of your database. It seems like you repeat columns quite a bit across them. Perhaps these can all be in a single table, with a "type" column that specifies whether it's power, construction, etc. Then you can query just the one table and group by country name to get all your results without the messy joins across 4 tables.

Comment: Hi thanks, I will check out,  IceMetalPunk I wish I could be able to make this as a single table but I can't figure out how for what I have do you think is possible to have a single table?

Comment: Absolutely, it's possible. Like I suggested, these all have the same three columns: Countries, Sum of No of Projects, and Sum of Total Budget Value ($m). So if you just create a table with those three columns, plus a "Type" column, you can put all the data in that one table, with "Type" specifying power, construction, etc. as needed. (Side note: column names really shouldn't have spaces or special characters like parentheses in them; it could cause code problems later if you're not very careful. Maybe change them to Countries, Project_Total, and Budget_Sum_M?)

Comment: I tried different combination but :( If you don't mind can you show me in excel??? really I tried I couldn't figure out

Comment: Use of implicit joins in SQL is not recommended. You should use `JOIN ON` clause

Comment: @Dharman As long as you're including a sufficient WHERE clause to ensure the join is as expected, is there any reason not to use implicit joins?

Comment: [Explicit JOINs vs Implicit joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53061517/1839439)

Comment: Hi guys as IceMetalPunk suggested me to use one table, I have updated the question and added bounty of 100 to it for a good answer

Answer (score 1):

The single table looks OK.

(The rest of this Answer is not complete, but might be useful.)

First, let's design the URL that will request the data.

```
.../foo.php?industry=...&country=...
```

But, rather than special casing the "all" in the client, do it in the server.  That is, the last button for industry will generate

```
    ?industry=all
```

and the PHP code will not include this in the `WHERE` clause:

```
    AND industry IN (...)
```

Similarly for `&country=all` versus `&country=egypt,iran,iraq`

Now, let me focus briefly on the PHP:

```
$wheres = array();

$industry = @$_GET['industry'];
if (! isset($industry)) { ...issue error message or use some default... }
elseif ($industry != 'all') {
    $inds = array();
    foreach (explode(',', $industry) as $ind) {
        // .. should test validity here; left to user ...
        $inds[] = "'$ind'";
    }
    $wheres[] = "industry IN (" . implode(',', $inds) . )";
}

// ... repeat for country ...

$where_clause = '';
if (! empty($wheres)) {
    $where_clause = "WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $wheres);
}
// (Note that this is a generic way to build arbitrary WHEREs from the data)

// Build the SQL:

$sql = "SELECT ... FROM ... 
           $where_clause
           ORDER BY ...";
// then execute it via mysqli or pdo (NOT mysql_query)
```

Now, let's talk about using AJAX.  Or not.  There were 2 choices:

- you could have had the call to PHP be via a `GET` and have that PHP display a new page.  This means that PHP will be constructing the table of results.
- you could have used AJAX to request the data.  This means that Javascript will be constructing the data of results.

Which choice to pick probably depends on which language you are more comfortable in.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but am confused little bit I have two php files `data.php` and `dataall.php`  do I need to add another php file like `allindsturies.php`, ? am not good in php, can you please put your answer in a clear way , that is why I added a bount of 100 because I needed a clear answer ,

Comment: @user9964622 - Only 1 php file for handling industries (all or some) and countries (all and some).  Note the test for "all".  The _code_ in the one .php interprets the url to decide what SQL to generate.  I wrote out about half the code.

Comment: You should not silence PHP errors with the `@`. Errors and warnings are your friends.

Comment: @Dharman - That _one_ use of `@` is an easy and concise way to say "this argument is optional _and I will check for it_.

Comment: It's neither easy nor needed. Either use null-coalescing operator or `isset` as you do in your `if`.

Comment: @Dharman - That is a very new feature; not everyone has it yet:  https://wiki.php.net/rfc/null_coalesce_equal_operator .  (Especially on cloud servers that are slow to upgade.)

Comment: @RickJames No, you are linking to the unary operator. I meant the [normal null-coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) which is available in PHP for a long time now and everyone has it. If someone does not use PHP 7.1 or higher then they have more serious problems they need to address first.

Comment: @Dharman - The title of that page is "Migrating from PHP 5.6.x to PHP 7.0.x".

Comment: @Dharman - What, in your opinion, are the "serious problems" that 7.1 fixes?