# Subquery to check date availability

Tags: mysql, sql

Could you help me with finding a solution to my query problem? I am stuck with it already for a week so I decided to try to ask for help and learn something. I am using MySQL database.

Right now I have a table without the "search feature".

```
SELECT
    r.rId,
    r.rName,
    r.rPrice,
    b.capacity
FROM
   room r,
   (SELECT roomId, SUM(bCapacity) AS capacity FROM bed GROUP BY roomId) AS b
WHERE r.rId = b.roomId;
```

This is the result:

[image: First query]

I want to show all rooms in the table that are not taken withing CHECK-IN and CHECK-OUT dates.

I have:

2 inputs:

- Check-In date
- Check-Out date

3 tables:

- room (I take id, name, price),
- bed (I sum capacity of beds in the given room),
- booking (here I want to check if certain roomId is taken)

And now I have a query that checks if any room is booked within a certain range.
And if the dates collide it returns me the table from booking with roomId.

```
SELECT
    roomId,
    bCheckIn,
    bCheckOut
FROM booking
WHERE (bCheckOut > ? AND bCheckIn <= ?) AND bStatus = 'Upcoming' OR 'Archived';
```

First ? is Check-In date and second ? is Check-Out date inputs.
Here I pass the above dates and returns rooms which are taken in the range of that date.

This is the result:

[image]

**SUMMARY**

Is it possible to combine those two queries so I will get only one table with first query data, but excluding those taken rooms from the second query? I failed with my query merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `not exists`:

```
select r.*
from rooms r
where not exists (select 1
                  from booking b
                  where b.roomid = r.id and
                        b.checkindate < :end_date and
                        b.checkoutdate >= :start_date
                 );
```

If you are learning SQL, you should learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: "Never use commas in the FROM clause" - I suppose that's a bit of a polarizing issue :)  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810515/is-there-an-oracle-official-recommendation-on-the-use-of-explicit-ansi-joins-vs).

Comment: @dcp . . . Everybody is, of course, entitled to their opinions.  But a 10-year old screen concerning shortcomings in the Oracle optimizer isn't really application to a MySQL question.

Comment: Fair enough.  However, your comment started with "If you are learning SQL...", which is more of a general statement, also not really specific to MySQL. I agree that there are good reasons to use ANSI JOIN syntax, but "Never use commas in the FROM clause" is more of a very strong opinion towards a specific coding style, and I think your answer would have been better if you had indicated that point. As you said, everybody is entitled to their opinions, and coding style preference is indeed, an opinion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I combined those two queries with your example and got wanted result :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query I combined with Gordon Linoff suggestion

```
SELECT r.rid            AS 'ID', 
   r.rname          AS 'Room Type', 
   r.rprice         AS 'Price (THB)', 
   Sum(b.bcapacity) AS 'Max Guests' 
FROM   room r 
       LEFT JOIN bed b 
              ON r.rid = b.roomid 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   booking bo 
                   WHERE  bo.roomid = r.rid 
                          AND bo.bcheckin < ? 
                          AND bo.bcheckout >= ?) 
GROUP  BY roomid;
```

And the result:

[image]

In this example, I have 2 booked rooms in the BOOKING table for dates of check-in '2020-06-08', check-out '2020-06-10'. I checked the same dates for above queries and it returned only rooms that are not booked within a given range.