# Join with Theta syntax in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have two simple tables let's say `country` and `state`. Suppose, I need to use `left join` on the `state` table. It can be written in MySql using ***ANSI*** syntax something like the one shown below.

```
select c.country_id, c.country_name, s.state_name 
from country c left join state s on s.country_id=c.country_id
```

In Oracle, the same SQL can be rewritten using ***Theta*** syntax as follows.

```
select c.country_id, c.country_name, s.state_name 
from country c, state s where s.country_id(+)=c.country_id
```

Can I write some way the preceding SQL (***Theta*** syntax) in **MySql**?, since I had been often using *Theta style* of SQL in Oracle.

Comment: I never heard that (horrible) syntax being called "Theta". Theta-joins (θ-joins) I thought were a generalization (`<`, `>`, `<=`, ...) to equal-joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use that (old Oracle) syntax in MySQL.

See this answer for **[why you should not be using that (old) syntax any more, not even in Oracle.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193654/different-between-oracles-plus-notation-over-ansi-join-notation)**