# Oracle select data from two tables and if one is empty return null

Tags: oracle, select, join

I have two tables (fruit_cost and fruit_availability) in oracle database, details below:
    
    **fruit_cost looks like this:**
    
    fruit_name | fruit_cost
    
    apple | 30
    
    orange | 7
    
    melon | 14
    
    **fruit_availability looks like this:**
    
    fruit_name | fruit_availability
    
    table is empty
    
    is there any good option to get results like these:
    
    fruit_name | fruit_cost | fruit_availability
    
    apple | 30 | null
    
    orange | 7 | null
    
    melon | 14 | null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just join the tables using a `LEFT JOIN`.

A `LEFT JOIN` will return all records in the `fruit_cost` table regardless of whether there is a matching record in the `fruit_availability` table. Your query will look like this:

```
select fc.fruit_name, 
  fc.fruit_cost,
  fa.fruit_availability
from fruit_cost fc
left join fruit_availability fa
  on fc.fruit_name = fa.fruit_name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ba9f/3)

The result is:

```
| FRUIT_NAME | FRUIT_COST | FRUIT_AVAILABILITY |
------------------------------------------------
|      melon |         14 |             (null) |
|     orange |          7 |             (null) |
|      apple |         30 |             (null) |
```

If you need help learning join syntax here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: @constantine while the syntax in the other answer is valid for oracle only, Oracle does recommend that you use `OUTER JOIN` syntax rather than the join operator. Here is a question explaining -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193654/difference-between-oracles-plus-notation-and-ansi-join-notation

Comment: Thanks for Your explanations, they were very helpful.

Comment: One more question to You, should I use LEFT JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN in my case (ORACLE DB) and what's the difference between these two syntaxes?

Comment: I have found this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server) but the article applies to MSSQL not ORACLE and that is why I'm still trapped :). Please help.

Comment: @constantine The `OUTER` is not required syntax when using a `JOIN`

Comment: I've made some changes and updates into my query. Now there are LEFT OUTER JOIN at three tables. All works perfectly. Thanks for explaining to me why shouldn't I use old methods. All links were very useful and helpful. Now I see the light in the tunnel :). It's easier to manipulate JOIN syntaxes in the FROM clause than (+) in the WHERE clause. Best regards.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle syntax:

```
select *
from fruit_cost fc, fruit_availability fa
where fc.fruit_name = fa.fruit_name (+);
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d889/1).

Comment: Best and shortest result 4 my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.fruit_name, c.fruit_cost, a.fruit_availability
from fruit_cost c 
   left outer join on fruit_availability a on
   c.fruit_name = a.fruit_name
order by c.fruit_name
```

Comment: select c.fruit_name, c.fruit_cost, a.fruit_availability
 from fruit_cost c left outer join fruit_availability a on c.fruit_name = a.fruit_name order by c.fruit_name