# Where clause is slowing my query from 2 seconds to 24 seconds

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to write a simple query to count the results from a big table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM DM.DM_CUSTOMER_SEG_BRIDGE_CORP_DW AL3
WHERE (AL3.REFERENCE_YEAR(+)   =2012)
```

Above query is taking around 24 seconds to return me output. If I remove where clause and execute same query, it is giving me result in 2 seconds.

May i know what is the reason for that. I am relatively new to SQL queries.

Please help

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 1):

You might need an index on the table. Typically you will need an index on any columns used in the where clause

as for the (+) syntax I think it is redundant (i'm no Oracle expert) but see [Difference between Oracle's plus (+) notation and ansi JOIN notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193654/difference-between-oracles-plus-notation-and-ansi-join-notation)

Comment: How can i check if the index exists for that table and column?

Comment: There are lots of free tools to view the structure of your database. You can also manage it from a command prompt.

Comment: alternatively you can look at the query plan eg EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT last_name FROM employees;

Comment: The (+) syntax is unnecessary in this case because you are not joining to any tables.

Answer (score 0):

The reason may seem subtle.  But there are multiple ways that Oracle could approach a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM DM.DM_CUSTOMER_SEG_BRIDGE_CORP_DW AL3
```

One way is to read all the rows in the table.  Because this is a big table, that is not the most efficient approach.  A second method would be to use statistics of some sort, where the number of rows are in the statistics.  I don't think Oracle ever does this, but it is conceivable.

The final method is to read an index.  Typically, an index would be much smaller than the table *and* it might already be in memory.  The above query would be reading a much smaller amount of data.  ([Here](http://www.oracledba.co.uk/tips/count_speed.htm) is an interesting article on counting all the rows in a table.)

When you introduce the `where` clause,

```
WHERE (AL3.REFERENCE_YEAR(+)   =2012)
```

Oracle can no longer scan just any index.  It would have to scan the `reference_year` index.  What is the problem?  If it scanned an index, it would still need to fetch the data records to get the value of `reference_year` -- and that is equivalent (actually worse) than scanning the whole table.

Even with an index on `reference_year`, you are not guaranteed to use the index.  The problem is something called *selectivity*.  The number of rows that you are fetching may still be quite large, relative to the number of rows in the database (in this context, 10% is "quite large").  The Oracle optimize may choose to do a full table scan rather than read the index.

Comment: Oracle supports index-only scans, if there is an index on `reference_year` it will not read anything from the table.  (Assuming this is the full query and there are no other predicates.)