# Outer join in case statement

Tags: oracle, outer-join

I have this below query:

```
SELECT U.NAME , U.TYPE , U.REFERENCED_NAME , U.REFERENCED_TYPE,
CASE 
WHEN U.REFERENCED_TYPE= 'TABLE' and A.TABLE_NAME= U.REFERENCED_NAME 
  THEN 'TABLE EXISTS'
WHEN U.REFERENCED_TYPE= 'PROCEDURE' and A.TABLE_NAME= U.REFERENCED_NAME 
   THEN 'PROCEDURE EXISTS'
END
FROM  USER_DEPENDENCIES U , user_tables a  
WHERE U.name ='RANDOM_PROCEDURE_NAME' and U.REFERENCED_NAME = A.TABLE_NAME;
```

My problem in this query is this :  **U.REFERENCED_NAME = A.TABLE_NAME** such join is giving ME only the specific condition.I want in table USER_DEPENDENCIES to know the tables that exists even if it doenst exists in table user_tables a. I WANT to include an outer join but I am not capable to do that. can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Are you talking about left outer join?

Comment: So you want all user_dependencies (referencing tables, procedures, triggers, ...)? And for those referencing a table or a procedure you want to know if there exists a table in user_tables with the same name as the referenced table or procedure? You are looking for procedures having the same name as tables in all_tables? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you all dependencies on your object. For tables and procedures it shows which of them exist in your database schema:

```
select dep.name , dep.type , dep.referenced_name , dep.referenced_type,
case 
  when dep.referenced_type = 'TABLE' and tab.table_name is not null then
    'TABLE EXISTS'
  when dep.referenced_type = 'PROCEDURE' and pro.procedure_name is not null then
    'PROCEDURE EXISTS'
end as lookup
from user_dependencies dep
left outer join user_tables tab on (dep.referenced_type = 'TABLE' and tab.table_name = dep.referenced_name) 
left outer join user_procedures pro on (dep.referenced_type = 'PROCEDURE' and pro.procedure_name = dep.referenced_name) 
where dep.name ='RANDOM_PROCEDURE_NAME';
```

Comment: this query was more efficient for me :)

Answer (score 1):

**Something like this?**

```
SELECT
      U.NAME,
      U.TYPE,
      U.REFERENCED_NAME,
      U.REFERENCED_TYPE,
      CASE
          WHEN U.REFERENCED_TYPE = 'TABLE'
              AND A.TABLE_NAME = U.REFERENCED_NAME
          THEN
              'TABLE EXISTS'
          WHEN U.REFERENCED_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
              AND A.TABLE_NAME = U.REFERENCED_NAME
          THEN
              'PROCEDURE EXISTS'
          ELSE
              'NOT DEFINED'
      END
          TYPE_1
FROM
      USER_DEPENDENCIES U,
      USER_TABLES A
WHERE
      U.NAME LIKE '%TEST%'
      AND U.REFERENCED_NAME = A.TABLE_NAME(+)
```

Comment: @Moudiz Update the query... Check now

Comment: realspirituals please can you give me a documentation or you can explain to me when do we use the (+) or the (-) ?

Comment: There is no (-) only (+) read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891148/oracle-joins-comparison-between-conventional-vs-join-operator-keyword THis has more links inside

Comment: The `(+)` syntax for outer joins is old and has limitations. Oracle itself suggests that `JOIN` syntax is used. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193654/difference-between-oracles-plus-notation-and-ansi-join-notation/1193722#1193722

Comment: @ypercube refer my commented link.

Comment: I have read the link you provided. But why do you answer the question with code that Oracle recommends not to use?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
FROM  
    USER_DEPENDENCIES u 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    user_tables a  
      ON u.REFERENCED_NAME = a.TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
    u.name ='RANDOM_PROCEDURE_NAME'  ;
```

All rows from the (left) table `USER_DEPENDENCIES`, no matter if they have a matching row at the `user_tables` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. Replace `WHERE` with `ON` your QUERY like this:

```
SELECT U.NAME , U.TYPE , U.REFERENCED_NAME , U.REFERENCED_TYPE,
CASE 
WHEN U.REFERENCED_TYPE= 'TABLE' and A.TABLE_NAME= U.REFERENCED_NAME 
  THEN 'TABLE EXISTS'
WHEN U.REFERENCED_TYPE= 'PROCEDURE' and A.TABLE_NAME= U.REFERENCED_NAME 
   THEN 'PROCEDURE EXISTS'
END
FROM  USER_DEPENDENCIES U 
LEFT JOIN user_tables a  
ON U.name ='RANDOM_PROCEDURE_NAME' and U.REFERENCED_NAME = A.TABLE_NAME;
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks. :)