# Query featuring outer joins behaves differently in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I had a problem come through concerning missing data on Oracle 12c.

I took a look at the code and found a query that works on mysql, mssql, oracle 11g, but has different behaviour in oracle 12c.

I have generalized the table structure and query somewhat and reproduced the issue.

```
create table thing (thing_id number, display_name varchar2(500));
create table thing_related (related_id number, thing_id number, thing_type varchar2(500));
create table type_a_status (related_id number, status varchar2(500));
create table type_b_status (related_id number, status varchar2(500));

insert into thing values (1, 'first');
insert into thing values (2, 'second');
insert into thing values (3, 'third');
insert into thing values (4, 'fourth');
insert into thing values (5, 'fifth');
insert into thing_related values (101, 1, 'TypeA');
insert into thing_related values (102, 2, 'TypeB');
insert into thing_related values (103, 3, 'TypeB');
insert into thing_related (related_id, thing_id) values (104, 4);

insert into type_a_status values (101, 'OK');
insert into type_b_status values (102, 'OK');
insert into type_b_status values (103, 'NOT OK');
```

Running the query:

```
SELECT t.thing_id AS id, t.display_name as name,
       tas.status as type_a_status,
       tbs.status as type_b_status
FROM thing t LEFT JOIN thing_related tr 
  ON t.thing_id = tr.thing_id
LEFT JOIN type_a_status tas 
  ON (tr.related_id IS NOT NULL 
      AND tr.thing_type = 'TypeA' 
      AND tr.related_id = tas.related_id)
LEFT JOIN type_b_status tbs 
  ON (tr.related_id IS NOT NULL 
      AND tr.thing_type = 'TypeB' 
      AND tr.related_id = tbs.related_id)
```

on Oracle 11g gives (here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b9ed/3)):

```
ID | NAME   | TYPE_A_STATUS | TYPE_B_STATUS
 1 | first  |            OK | (null)
 2 | second |        (null) | OK
 3 | third  |        (null) | NOT OK
 4 | fourth |        (null) | (null)
 5 | fifth  |        (null) | (null)
```

Yet the same schema, data, and query on Oracle 12c:

```
ID | NAME   | TYPE_A_STATUS | TYPE_B_STATUS
 1 | first  |            OK | (null)
 2 | second |        (null) | OK
 3 | third  |        (null) | NOT OK
 4 | fourth |        (null) | (null)
```

It seems that the second two outer joins are failing to bring back anything because there is no row in 'thing_related' to join by. However I don't understand why the outer join does not return nulls in this case as it does in Oracle 11g, Mysql, etc..

I've been researching and found documentation the Oracle 12c had a number of enhancements for outer joins, but nothing that highlighted a change that would affect this.

Does anyone know why this is happening only for Oracle 12c, and how best would I rewrite this to work in 12c and maintain compatibility with 11g, mysql, etc.?

EDIT: Attached plans.

Oracle 11g:

[image]

Oracle 12c:

[image]

Comment: did you compare the plans?

Comment: I have attached. I see the 11g shows a HASH JOIN OUTER, where 12c shows HASH JOIN.

Comment: I dont have access to 12c... but i remember the improvement in 12c wrt plans for processing JOINS. Do have a look at that, which may throw some lights

Comment: This is probably a bug.  I see a lot of related bugs in My Oracle Support, but no exact match.  But I could easily be missing something.  You'll probably need to submit a service request with Oracle.  This sounds like a really bad bug, they should be able to either find an existing bug or create a new one.  Usually with these kinds of bugs if you make very minor changes to the query they may go way.  The first thing to try is to remove the redundant condition `tr.related_id IS NOT NULL`.  Since the ID is joined on an equality operator there's no need to also check if it's not null.

Comment: Removing the redundant IS NOT NULLs has no effect. Interestingly the following does make the query come back as it did pre-12c:  `LEFT JOIN type_a_status tas ON ((tr.thing_type = 'TypeA' or tr.thing_type = 'TypeB') AND tr.related_id = tas.related_id)`  `LEFT JOIN type_b_status tbs ON (tr.thing_type = 'TypeB' AND tr.related_id = tbs.related_id)`

Comment: My suggestion would go back to the conventional syntax (+) instead of ANSI syntax to check if it works well. Because there were some  bugs on ANSI syntax and solved on 11.2.XXX

Comment: We are using Oracle 12.1.0.2. At this time we discovered a bug where oracle returns the wrong data while the number of rows was correct. Minor modifications to the query - removing certain fields, reshuffling conditions, or re-writing the query using the ansi syntax inner joins - lead to the correct result. Also, oracle might return the correct result but subsequent executions would bring the wrong data. For now we set optimizer_adaptive_features=FALSE. That fixed the issue with the query. My advice: DO NOT USE the adaptive features!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This is fixed in 12.1.0.2.

---

This definitely looks like a bug in 12.1.0.1.  I would encourage you to create a service request through Oracle support.  They might be able to find a fix or a better work around.  And hopefully Oracle can fix it in a future version for everyone.  Normally the worst part about working with support is reproducing the issue.  But since you already have a very good test case this issue may be easy to resolve.

There are probably many ways to work around this bug.  But it's difficult to tell which method will always work.  Your query re-write may work now, but if optimizer statistics change perhaps the plan will change back in the future.

Another option that works for me on 12.1.0.1.0 is:

```
ALTER SESSION SET optimizer_features_enable='11.2.0.3';
```

But you'd need to remember to always change this setting before the query is run, and then change it back to '12.1.0.1' after.  There are ways to embed that within a query hint, such as `/*+ OPT_PARAM('optimizer_features_enable' '11.2.0.3') */`.  But for some reason that does not work here.  Or perhaps you can temporarily set that for the entire system and change it back after a fix or better work around is available.

Whichever solution you use, remember to document it.  If a query looks odd the next developer may try to "fix" it and hit the same problem.

Comment: Thanks. We will put in a service request with Oracle.

Comment: @amcintosh did you ever get a response from Oracle? I am seeing this issue on a new install

Comment: @JordanBentley Unfortunately no.

Comment: @Jon: In your post you said: "This definitely looks like a bug in 12.2.0.1". Is the version 12.2.0.1 correct? If not, could you please correct it? It is confusing when you read the message.

Comment: @Costa You're right, thanks for pointing that out!  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Refer to:

ANSI Outer Join Query Returns Wrong Results After Upgrade to 12.1.0.1 (Doc ID 1957943.1)

Unpublished bug 16726638

Fixed in 12.1.0.2 (I have tested this)

Workaround (I tested in 12.1.0.1):

```
alter session set "_optimizer_ansi_rearchitecture"=false;
```

Note 1957943.1 recommends as an alternative:

```
optimizer_features_enable = '11.2.0.4';
```

but that does *not* work.

Answer (score -1):

I've a migration planned from 11gR2 to 12c and whole lot of syntax is in ANSI. Its really a nightmare to test each and every query and compare it with the 11g data. Is setting alter session set "_optimizer_ansi_rearchitecture"=false;       is the only solution or the bug is fixed