# How can I insert date and time in date type?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I want to insert date and time into my database `"create_date_time"` column please let me know how can I do that

Below is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE colleague_rx_audit (
 rx_audit_id Integer NOT NULL,
 colleague_email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 store_num Integer NOT NULL,
 role_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 action varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 create_date_time date NOT NULL
);
```

and I'm this code block for insertion :

```
$addressData['CUSTOMER_ID'] = $this->session->userdata('CUSTOMER_ID'); 
$addressData['BUILDING_NAME'] = $this->input->post('building_name'); 
$addressData['HOUSE_NUM'] = $this->input->post('house_num'); 
$addressData['CREATE_DATE_TIME'] = strtoupper(date("d-M-y h:i:s")); 
$addressData['LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME'] = strtoupper(date("d-M-y h:i:s")); 
$result = $this->db->insert('CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES',$addressData);
```

Comment: Can you include your current insert script?

Comment: ```
$addressData['CUSTOMER_ID'] = $this->session->userdata('CUSTOMER_ID');
               $addressData['BUILDING_NAME'] = $this->input->post('building_name');
               $addressData['HOUSE_NUM'] = $this->input->post('house_num');
               
               $addressData['CREATE_DATE_TIME'] = strtoupper(date("d-M-y h:i:s"));
               $addressData['LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME'] = strtoupper(date("d-M-y h:i:s"));


$result = $this->db->insert('CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES',$addressData);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle Joins - Comparison between conventional syntax VS ANSI Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891148/oracle-joins-comparison-between-conventional-syntax-vs-ansi-syntax)