# What is mean the condition COUNT(1) = 1 in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have two table and write select:

```
SELECT A.code, B.account, A.ano 
FROM atable A, dtable B 
where A.ano=B.dno
group by A.code, B.account, A.ano 
having count(1)=1;
```

if I add condition having count(1)=1 I didn't get any result, why?

Comment: I guess you don't have `A.code_uv, B.account, A.cif_no` combinations that occur just once

Comment: Side note: [Comparison between conventional syntax VS ANSI Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18891148/205233)

Comment: `count(1)` is just an eccentric way of writing `count(*)`. I'd advise sticking with the standard version.

Answer (score 2):

Query groups data per columns listed in the `GROUP BY` clause. `HAVING` restricts result set to those whose count (for those grouped columns) equals `1`.

If query returns nothing, it means that there's not at least one combination of those columns that has only one row as a result.

For example (based on Scott's EMP table):

```
SQL> select job, count(*) from emp
  2  group by job;

JOB         COUNT(*)
--------- ----------
CLERK              4
SALESMAN           4
PRESIDENT          1      --> only one person is a president
MANAGER            3
ANALYST            2
```

Your query:

```
SQL> select job
  2  from emp
  3  group by job
  4  having count(*) = 1;

JOB
---------
PRESIDENT
```

Let's set someone else to be a president:

```
SQL> update emp set job = 'PRESIDENT' where ename = 'ADAMS';

1 row updated.
```

The query doesn't return anything now (as there are 2 presidents):

```
SQL> select job
  2  from emp
  3  group by job
  4  having count(*) = 1;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

---

As of `count(1)`: no point in it, use `count(*)` instead.

Comment: Thanks it is very clear and now I understand