# Select top n-random rows from table, where n is in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

Let's say I have a table `B`:

| client_id | n_periods | qtty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 200 |
| 2 | 3 | 100 |
| 3 | 8 | 150 |

And then I have a (large) table `foo`:

| client_id | date | period | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | 3000 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2 | 2800 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 24 | 2800 |
| 2 | 2022-01-05 | 1 | 3500 |
| 2 | 2022-01-05 | 2 | 3500 |
| 2 | 2022-01-05 | 24 | 3500 |

I want to randomly `SELECT` the top B.n_periods `FROM FOO WHERE B.client_id = foo.client_id`. I other words, I want to randomly select n-rows for each client_id in `foo`, where the n-rows is given in table `B` also for each client_id. I also want to perform a simple substraction foo.amount minus B.qtty.

I have tried:

```
SELECT
TOP B.n_periods
foo.client_id,
foo.date,
foo.period,
foo.amount - B.qtty
FROM B, foo
```

But I get the error:
`[42000][923] ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

I am a bit lost, I have tried using `CONNECT BY` but maybe I don't understand well how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shuffle rows per partition, then choose the first n rows for particular client:

```
select s.*
from (
  select f.*
       , row_number() over (partition by f.client_id order by dbms_random.random()) as rn
  from foo f
) s
join b on s.client_id = b.client_id and s.rn <= b.n_periods
```

(I didn't tested it. Providing data sample could increase quality of my answer.)

Comment: I provided some data, but maybe it's not properly formatted and thus you don't see it, can you?
Also I understand the logic of your query but it doesn't work, I think the problem is in `shuffled s`. I think you meant just `s`.

Comment: @NicolásRivera Corrected, thanks. "To provide data" means to create reproducible example on sites like dbfiddle.uk or similar. It helps to concentrate on answer instead of text formatting.

Comment: I know the data I provided was rather sacarse. Nevertheless, your answer worked.
I just wanted to comment that instead of `JOIN` I used implicit inner join:
```SELECT * FROM s, b WHERE s.client_id = b.client_id...```

Comment: @NicolásRivera yes, it will certainly work as well with old-style joins. I am just from the camp of those who find ansi joins more readable (good question on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18891148/653539)). Glad to hear it helped you.