# how do I modify my having clause so my query will show the result that I want

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, having

So currently my query shows result of all the "preferred" travel destinations of countries based on the continent, and I'm adding a having clause to show the continents that have more than 1 preferred destination. But as I soon as I add more columns I want to show, let's the say cities, my query returns nothing.

This is the query that work, it shows all continents that have more than 2 preferred countries as travel destination(the preferred flag is Y).

```
select  d.continent,d.country_name,di.is_preferred, count(1)
from continent c, countries ct
where c.cid = ct.id
and ct.preferred = Y
group by   d.continent,d.country_name,ct.is_preferred
having count(1) > 1
order by d.country_name asc;`
```

Let's say I want to have the same result showing, but I want to show all the list of cities of the countries that where continent have more than 1 preferred country. The cities column is from continent C table, as soon as I add to the having statement, the result is blank?

What did I do wrong?

Here is my modified query:

```
select  d.continent,d.country_name,di.is_preferred, c.cities, count(1)
from continent c, countries ct
where c.cid = ct.id
and ct.preferred = Y
group by   d.continent,d.country_name,ct.is_preferred, c.cities
having count(1) > 1
order by d.country_name asc;
```

I've tried modified my queries but got nothing in my result

Comment: Is it possible that the data doesn't return results? It is correct there is nothing to return?
Also I'm not sure why continent.id is equal to country.id, maybe that's a separate issue, though perhaps you mean c.id = ct.continent_id  or similar?

Comment: [Oracle Joins - Comparison between conventional syntax VS ANSI Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891148/oracle-joins-comparison-between-conventional-syntax-vs-ansi-syntax)

Comment: I just meant if I want to show all the cities belong to the continent that have more than 2 preferred countries as destination, the result became blank? Group by is by cities is somehow causing the error.

Comment: Very odd to have a cities column in the continents table. I'd expect a separate cities table, with fk's to countries and continents.

Comment: Your query has lots of syntax errors as you use the aliases `d` and `di` in the `SELECT` clause but you define the table aliases as `c` and `ct` in the `FROM` clause and then mix the aliases in the `WHERE` clause. Please [edit] your question and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data and the expected output for that sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to show all the list of cities of the countries that where continent have more than 1 preferred country.

If you `GROUP BY continent, country_name` then you are finding the pairing of continent and country where there are 2-or-more preferred entries; if you want it by `continent` only (as per the question) then you only want to `GROUP BY continent`.

If you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE continent (cid, continent) AS
  SELECT 1, 'Africa'        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Asia'          FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'South America' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE countries (id, country_name, is_preferred, cities) AS
  SELECT 1, 'Dominican Republic', 'Y', 'Kinshasa'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Nigeria',            'Y', 'Lagos'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Egypt',              'Y', 'Cairo'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'China',              'N', 'Shanghai'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Pakistan',           'Y', 'Karachi'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Brazil',             'Y', 'Sao Paulo' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Peru',               'Y', 'Lima'      FROM DUAL;
```

and you want to `GROUP BY` each `continent` and show a list of the preferred `cities` then only `GROUP BY continent` and use `LISTAGG` to aggregate the names of the cities into a delimited list:

```sql
SELECT c.continent,
       LISTAGG(ct.cities, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cities) AS cities
FROM   continent c
       INNER JOIN countries ct
       ON c.cid = ct.id
WHERE  ct.is_preferred = 'Y'
GROUP BY
       c.continent
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY
       c.continent;
```

Which outputs:

| CONTINENT | CITIES |
| --- | --- |
| Africa | Cairo,Kinshasa,Lagos |
| South America | Lima,Sao Paulo |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AhNyEic7)