# sql outer join shows the error in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables `country` and `state`:

```
country
-----------
cid
countrycode
countryname

state
-------
sid
cid (fk)
statecode
statename
```

I am writing a join as:

```
SELECT s.sid, 
       s.statename, 
       c.countryname 
FROM   state s, 
       country c 
WHERE  s.cid = (+) c.cid 
       AND c.id = 1
```

The above query gives a syntax error. Does MySQL not accept '+' symbol?

Comment: Whats with the plus sign?

Comment: @Mihai the plus sign is outer join .

Comment: @AnkitSharma the plus sign is outer join symbol.

Comment: `+` is a non-ANSI standard way of saying [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Alternate_syntaxes).

Comment: @AnkitSharma Just because you never used it, doesn't mean it's wrong. The world doesn't revolve around MySQL.

Comment: (+) apparently is an atavism from the Jurassic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193654/difference-between-oracles-plus-notation-and-ansi-join-notation

Comment: @Mihai Jurassic or not, some are still taught this notation or must use it.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @AnkitSharma [*...the + notation is only present for backwards compatibility because Oracle debuted it before the ANSI standard for joins was put in place.*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193654/difference-between-oracles-plus-notation-and-ansi-join-notation)

Comment: @Ankit <facepalm> he's saying that some people must use it because they are dealing with legacy code or old-school colleagues.

Comment: And the `WHERE s.cid = (+) c.cid` would yield an error in Oracle as well. The old Oracle syntax would be either `WHERE s.cid = c.cid (+)` (meaning: `s LEFT JOIN c`) or `WHERE s.cid (+) = c.cid` (meaning: `s RIGHT JOIN c`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, MySQL does not accept the `+` symbol. Aside from a few exceptions, MySQL uses ANSI standard `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT s.sid, 
       s.statename, 
       c.countryname 
FROM   state s 
       LEFT JOIN country c 
              ON c.id = s.cid 
WHERE  c.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
select 
s.sid,
s.statename,
c.countryName 
from country c 
LEFT JOIN state s on  s.cid = c.cid 
WHERE c.id=1
```

Comment: `+` is a non-ANSI standard way of saying [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Alternate_syntaxes).

Answer (score 0):

**Remove plus sign** and **.** symbol at end of your query...

```
Select s.sid,s.statename,c.countryName from state s,
left join country c on s.cid = c.cid where c.id=1
```

Comment: `+` is a non-ANSI standard way of saying [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Alternate_syntaxes).

Comment: Ok.. But one more  , am not recommend a outer join , but user wants to skip from the error, so only i suggest.. Thanks for comment..

Answer (score 0):

this will help you.

```
 SELECT s.sid, 
       s.statename, 
       c.countryname 
FROM   country c 
LEFT JOIN state s on (s.cid = c.cid )
where c.cid = 1;
```

Comment: `+` is a non-ANSI standard way of saying [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Alternate_syntaxes).