# Row that should have a 0 count not showing

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm working through a problem, working with SQL Oracle. I'm getting the right results beside a row that should be showing up that has a count of 0. The question is

**Question:**

For each section of the Project Management course, list the section ID, location and number of students enrolled. Sort by section ID.

**My Code:**

```
SELECT s.Section_Id, s.Location, COUNT(*) AS Enrolled
FROM Course c, Section s,  Enrollment e
WHERE c.Course_No = s.Course_No
  AND s.Section_Id = e.Section_Id
  AND c.Description = 'Project Management'
GROUP BY  c.Course_No, s.Location, s.Section_Id
ORDER BY s.Section_Id;
```

**My Results:**

```
SECTION_ID    LOCATION                ENROLLED
----------    -------------------     ----------
48            L211                    4 
119           L211                    3 
120           L214                    2
```

**Expected Results:**

```
SECTION_ID    LOCATION                ENROLLED
----------    -------------------     ----------
48            L211                    4
119           L211                    3
120           L214                    2
121           L507                    0
```

So as you can see I'm missing the row with 0 enrolled on my results and can't seem to get that row to appear. Also you will notice that it is a section id and location that go with it for that project management class but it won't appear. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be great, also [here is the Schema](http://authors.phptr.com/rischert/documents/AppendixD.pdf).

DBMS: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: You are going to have to do a left join to enrollment.  Then you'll need to use either nvl() or coalesce to replace the null values with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about joining to the tables instead of using the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT s.Section_Id, 
       s.Location, 
       COUNT(e.Section_Id) AS Enrolled 
FROM   course c 
       LEFT JOIN section s 
              ON c.Course_No = s.Course_No 
       LEFT JOIN enrollment e 
              ON s.Section_Id = e.Section_Id 
WHERE  c.Description = 'Project Management' 
GROUP  BY c.Course_No, 
          s.Location, 
          s.Section_Id 
ORDER  BY s.Section_Id;
```

Comment: That is showing the row now but for some reason show enrolled as 1?

Comment: @OmniSquad, I modified my answer

Comment: Okay I got it with this answer I added Student_Id into the count and took out c.Course_No in group by and it worked! Also your updated answer worked !

Answer (score 0):

You need to outer join to course and enrollment otherwise you won't see sections that don't have any courses/enrollments. You can either use the ANSI syntax ...LEFT JOIN... etc or the old Oracle syntax using (+) against the columns of the deficient table:-

```
SELECT s.Section_Id, s.Location, COUNT(*) AS Enrolled
FROM Course c, Section s,  Enrollment e
WHERE c.Course_No (+) = s.Course_No
  AND s.Section_Id = e.Section_Id (+)
  AND c.Description (+) = 'Project Management'
GROUP BY  c.Course_No, s.Location, s.Section_Id
ORDER BY s.Section_Id;
```

These days I would use the ANSI syntax...

Comment: Oracle discourages the use of the old style, proprietary `(+)` syntax for outer joins. You should really start using the explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Non-ANSI joins should be used for backward compatibility, not for new development ([related question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1193722/335858)).

Answer (score 0):

@OmniSquad you could use SQL provided by Linger to create LEFT OUTER JOIN and select records where is no enrolment and  changes statement COUNT(e.Section_Id) AS Enrolled.