# (+) next to column name in Oracle sql statement

Tags: oracle

I have a oracle query statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE1 sc, TABLE2 sr
WHERE  sc.TABLE_ID(+)='T1000'   
AND    sc.TABLE_VALID(+)='Y'  
AND    sc.TABLE_VALUE(+)=sr.STATUS
```

- What is (+) next to each column name in where clause?
- What (+) is doing in this oracle select query?
- What's the difference with or without (+) in this query?

I executed this query with or without (+), but couldn't see any difference in query results.
I googled it, but couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Difference between Oracle's plus (+) notation and ansi JOIN notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193654).

Comment: (+) is basically an `outer join`, you should search using `OUTER JOIN` instead