# Oracle left join sql query issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, left-join

I have one SQL query in which they have used `Left-Join` feature and now there is a requirement to convert it into operator (+) syntax. Please guide me how to do it, The query is as written below :

```
select (some field names) 
from
ldcs2.component comp
LEFT JOIN ldcs2.component_detail cd
   ON cd.component_id = comp.component_id
LEFT JOIN ldcs2.component_item_breakdown cib
   ON cib.component_item_id = cd.component_item_id
```

So please guide me what does Left-Join specify here and how can we write it into (+) expression.
Also guide me as they have mentioned second mapping table (**ldcs2.component_detail**) at first in `ON` condition, whether it would work differently if we write at first in that condition or not?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you could do, but I have to note that personally I prefer the ANSI way.

There are two sides of a join condition. When you use ANSI syntax and code `A left join B`, you imply that for a record in A, there is no need to be a match on B.

When you put (+) on a specific side of the join condition you imply something like "The field on this side of the condition need not to be matched."

```
select (some field names) 
from
    ldcs2.component comp,
    ldcs2.component_detail cd,
    ldcs2.component_item_breakdown cib 
where
    cd.component_id (+) = comp.component_id
    and cib.component_item_id (+) = cd.component_item_id
```

Comment: please find the full code at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538400/left-join-vs-ansi-format-issue], as i am not getting the same result by using both type of queries

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the ANSI/ISO Syntax to Oracle outer join syntax as follows -

```
SELECT (SOME field names)
FROM ldcs2.component comp,
  ldcs2.component_detail cd,
  ldcs2.component_item_breakdown cib
WHERE comp.component_id     = cd.component_id(+)
AND cd.component_item_id = cib.component_item_id(+)
/
```

> So please guide me what does Left-Join specify here and how can we write it into (+) expression.

For a detailed understanding, see my previous answer on a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28499208/3989608

Comment: please find the full code at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538400/left-join-vs-ansi-format-issue], as i am not getting the same result by using both type of queries

Comment: In your other question, the two SQLs are different since you have an additional join.

Comment: my dear friend, both the queries are the exact match, but when i tried with ANSI expression, i am unable to fetch the records when dealing with Outer Joining multiple tables, do you know something about this