# What is (+) at the end of the query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm quite new to oracle sql and just ran into a query that looks something like this

```
SELECT some_field
FROM some_table
WHERE some_other_field=some_value(+);
```

I simplified and annonimized the code, but im curious  whats the `(+)` at the end. I don't remember seeing that in mssql world ever.

Comment: Please see my detailed answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28499208/3989608

Comment: Probably more a duplicate of [What does `(+)` do in a WHERE clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430274/oracle-what-does-do-in-a-where-clause)

Comment: Please note, that this is deprecated (but still accepted) by Oracle since 9i R2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Oracle old outer join syntax:

> To write a query that performs an outer join of tables A and B and
>   returns all rows from A (a left outer join), use the LEFT [OUTER] JOIN
>   syntax in the FROM clause, or apply the outer join operator (+) to all
>   columns of B in the join condition in the WHERE clause. For all rows
>   in A that have no matching rows in B, Oracle Database returns null for
>   any select list expressions containing columns of B.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm