# What does the (+) operator mean in a where-clause of PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a SQL query something like:-

```
Select Table1.attr1, Table1.attr2, Table2.attr3, Table2.attr4
From Tab1 Tabel1, Tab2 Tabel2
Where Tabel1.Attr = Tabel2.Attr (+)
```

So what does the above mean? Is this a right outer join?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: What does `(+)` do in a WHERE clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430274/oracle-what-does-do-in-a-where-clause)

Comment: Yup... It is duplicate of that. I found it now when u pointed it out. I have been googling this for days but always ended up in something else.

Comment: I knew it was out there and still had some trouble locating it :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it means right join. if the statement was like .... where Tabel1.Attr (+) = Tabel2.Attr, it have to be left join.

Comment: Fasle, see documentation https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php 
As a final note, it is worth mentioning that the LEFT OUTER JOIN example above could be rewritten using the older implicit syntax that utilizes the outer join operator (+) as follows (but we still recommend using the LEFT OUTER JOIN keyword syntax):

SELECT suppliers.supplier_id, suppliers.supplier_name, orders.order_date
FROM suppliers, orders
WHERE suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id(+);

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a LEFT OUTER JOIN (although the currently approved answer says it's a RIGHT OUTER JOIN). From [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_10002.htm#i2066611):

```
Using Outer Joins: Examples

SELECT d.department_id, e.last_name
   FROM departments d LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e
   ON d.department_id = e.department_id
   ORDER BY d.department_id;


Users familiar with the traditional Oracle Database outer
joins syntax will recognize the same query in this form:

SELECT d.department_id, e.last_name
   FROM departments d, employees e
   WHERE d.department_id = e.department_id (+)
   ORDER BY d.department_id;
```

For the RIGHT OUTER JOIN you put the (+) sign before the = sign, eg.

```
SELECT d.department_id, e.last_name
   FROM departments d, employees e
   WHERE d.department_id (+) = e.department_id
   ORDER BY d.department_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, the + is a right join

Answer (score 3):

This is a a LEFT OUTER JOIN. You can find an example of using one here: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php

Comment: OT: Sorry, I voted down this answer by mistake, and it seems I'm not allowed to undo the downvote unless the answer is edited :(

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Table1.attr1, Table1.attr2, Table2.attr3, Table2.attr4
From Tab1 Tabel1, Tab2 Tabel2
Where Tabel1.Attr = Tabel2.Attr (+)
```

The same with the recognizable syntax:

```
Select Table1.attr1, Table1.attr2, Table2.attr3, Table2.attr4 From Tab1 Tabel1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tab2 Tabel2 on Tabel1.Attr = Tabel2.Attr
```