# What does "(+)" mean in SQL syntax?

Tags: oracle, join, syntax

I came across a SQL join syntax as follows:

```
Select
ColList
From 
Tablename1, Tablename2
Where
Tablename1.ColName (+)= Tablename2.ColName
And
Tablename1.ColName2 = Tablename2.ColName2
```

Now I understand the basic SQL join syntax but (+) sign is little confusing. Can someone please explain me what this (+) sing means? 
Thanks

Comment: Also possibly [What does `(+)` do in a WHERE clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430274/oracle-what-does-do-in-a-where-clause)

Comment: this was already asked, found the correct answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559261/left-outer-join-using-sign-in-oracle-11g