# Oracle (+) operator equal number

Tags: sql, oracle

I know what (+) operator does in this query:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM
   TBL_TEST t, TBL_TEST_2 t2
WHERE
   t.FIELD (+) = t2.FIELD;
```

But what (+) operator does in such query as:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM
   TBL_TEST t
WHERE
   t.FIELD (+) = 2;
```

I don't know...

Can someone explain it?

Comment: Old Oracle syntax for outer join?

Comment: [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430274/oracle-what-does-do-in-a-where-clause)

Comment: @user2877959 I don't think it's duplicate... I know what (+) do in joins. I edit my question for better understanding my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: What does \`(+)\` do in a WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430274/oracle-what-does-do-in-a-where-clause)

Comment: This the legacy syntax for denoting an out join. Without a join this makes no sense, even if you can write it.

Comment: @Gadziu it's still a left join. It just doesn't make any sense

Comment: Ok, I think the same... I review code for someone else, and I saw somethign like this and it doesn't make sanse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have an example**

```
    select * from xxtest
V_ID    V_NAME  V_ADDRESS
5   PriceList   349FDAFD34M
7   PriceList   349FDAFD34M
7   Footer1 349FDAFD34M
5   Footer1 349FDAFD34M
5   Header1 349FDAFD34M
7   Header1 349FDAFD34M




 select * from xxtest2
V_ID    V_NAME  V_ADDRESS
7   Header1 349FDAFD34M
```

**query 01**

```
    select * 
    from xxtest aa, xxtest2 bb 
    where aa.v_id = bb.v_id(+) and bb.v_id(+) = 7
V_ID    V_NAME  V_ADDRESS   V_ID    V_NAME  V_ADDRESS
7   PriceList   349FDAFD34M 7   Header1 349FDAFD34M
7   Footer1 349FDAFD34M 7   Header1 349FDAFD34M
7   Header1 349FDAFD34M 7   Header1 349FDAFD34M
5   PriceList   349FDAFD34M  -   -   - 
5   Footer1 349FDAFD34M  -   -   - 
5   Header1 349FDAFD34M  -   -   -
```

**query 02**

```
    select * 
    from xxtest aa, xxtest2 bb 
    where aa.v_id = bb.v_id(+) and bb.v_id = 7
V_ID    V_NAME  V_ADDRESS   V_ID    V_NAME  V_ADDRESS
7   PriceList   349FDAFD34M 7   Header1 349FDAFD34M
7   Footer1 349FDAFD34M 7   Header1 349FDAFD34M
7   Header1 349FDAFD34M 7   Header1 349FDAFD34M
```

Hope it's will help u.

Comment: Thank's a lot:) So it have kind of sanse now :D

Answer (score 0):

To force Oracle to confess it's outer join

```
select *
from ( select 1 n from dual
  ) t
where n (+) = n+1
```

> ORA-01416: two tables cannot be outer-joined to each other

:)

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in Oracle 12G, and it returns the same result as:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM
   TBL_TEST t
WHERE
   t.FIELD = 2;
```

My guess for the original code is trying to say if the field eques 2, return the field value, otherwise return null. Something like below:

```
SELECT T.STUDENT, T2.*
  FROM TBL_TEST T
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 2 COLU FROM DUAL) T2 ON T.COUNT = T2.COLU;
```