# SQL (+) notation in query

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

When using (+), can you only use this once in a statement? For example when I run this query it gives an error: "a predicate may reference only one outer-joined table"

```
SELECT C.COURSE_NO, C.DESCRIPTION, S.SECTION_ID, 
S.COURSE_NO, S.START_DATE_TIME
FROM COURSE C, SECTION S
WHERE C.COURSE_NO (+) = S.COURSE_NO (+);
```

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Comment: Please read the manual when you are using a feature & if still stuck google. This is all explained in the manual. Also in all the SO duplicate answers to people who didn't read the manual or google.

Answer (score 0):

Not "once in a statement", but **"one in a relation"**.
Depending on are you using (+) can denotes a LEFT or RIGHT join. If you use in both sides you're trying somenthing like "left and right join", that is impossible.

You can use `C.COURSE_NO (+) = S.COURSE_NO` or  `C.COURSE_NO = S.COURSE_NO (+)`

And you can use more than one in a complete statement, like this:

```
table1.id (+) = table2.id
and
table3.id = table4.id(+)
```

Related questions:

[Oracle what does do in a where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430274/oracle-what-does-do-in-a-where-clause)

[Difference between Oracle's plus (+) notation and ansi JOIN notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193654/difference-between-oracles-plus-notation-and-ansi-join-notation)

Answer (score 0):

The now ancient pre-ANSI standards Oracle syntax for an outer join doesn't support other join types like the full outer join you are trying to do with `(+)` on both sides.

It is supported to not break old code. You should not be using it for new code - use the ANSI SQL standard JOIN syntax.

```
SELECT C.COURSE_NO, C.DESCRIPTION, S.SECTION_ID, S.COURSE_NO, S.START_DATE_TIME
FROM COURSE C 
FULL OUTER JOIN SECTION S ON C.COURSE_NO = S.COURSE_NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do a full outer join. That would look like this in standard ANSI:

```
SELECT C.COURSE_NO, C.DESCRIPTION, S.SECTION_ID, 
S.COURSE_NO, S.START_DATE_TIME
FROM COURSE C 
FULL OUTER JOIN SECTION S
ON C.COURSE_NO = S.COURSE_NO;
```